# Examples of Spartan Programming in C#

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, spartan

I am interested in reading examples of code in C# that makes use of the [Spartan Programming](http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Spartan_programming) philosophy.  Can you please provide a link to any open source project or online code sample that follows this coding style?

Comment: Why'd you make it Community Wiki?

Comment: George, given that there is no definitive answer to this question, and as it is really a list of links/resources, I thought making it a community wiki was appropriate.  Also, it stopped the usual Community Wiki Fascists chiming in with the usual "I think this should be a ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is in Java and not C#, and maybe you've already read it, but this is an excellent article: http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/SendAnEmail_case_study

Comment: Klausbyskov, accepted as the answer, despite not being in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/OferRubinstein/20091114/3559/BJBK_4_Reviewing_the_code_of_revision_10first_milestone.php) on the [Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/) website has a review of C# code written using the Spartan programming style, with a solution that may be downloaded for review.  An example of the code is:

```
virtual public void Update(float t, Camera c)
{
    Vector2 a = new Vector2(0, PixelsPerMeter*9.8f);
    Velocity = Velocity + a * t;
    Position = Position + Velocity * t; // Like n*(n-1)/2
    Position.Y = MathHelper.Min(FloorY, Position.Y);
    Velocity.Y = (Position.Y==0.0)?MathHelper.Min(0, Velocity.Y):Velocity.Y;
}
```